# Cannot obtain value of timestamp

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am having problems obtaining a column from SQL Server.

The DB has a column of type `timestamp`, and I am trying to set the value in Java, but I get the following message error message:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:the conversion type timestamp to TIMESTAMP is not compatible.`

My Java code is :

```
dtoOperacion.setExtractionDate(rs.getTimestamp(7));
```

The property `extractionDate` is type `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Is there a type specified by JDBC Sql Server that I can use for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong datatype in your table in the first place. You should be using a Datetime instead of the TimeStamp data type. As per SQL server documentation Timestamp is-

"Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type."

Comment: Thats exactly it. JDBC Timestamp is the equivalent of SQL-Server Datetime column type. JDBC Time is the equivalent of an SQL-Server Timestamp. Can be confusing :)

Comment: thanks, i think that the design of the dto is bad, and your answer confirm it.

Comment: For the SQL Server data type, consider using datetime2 as that allows a specified precision and requires less storage that datetime.  The SQL Server data type name timestamp (alias for rowversion) is deprecated since it very confusing as you have found.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012, at least, [the MSDN page on JDBC data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878.aspx) suggests you should be using JDBC's BINARY type.

Comment: No worries, glad you found the right answer! Feel free to upvote this answer as well if it was helpful, though I agree that the one you accepted was the one that most thoroughly fixed your problem. :)